# Disabling Related Videos via YouTube iFrame API

Tags: youtube, youtube-iframe-api

Tried this code I found on a Google code to disable related videos, but I still get related videos when the video ends:

```
YT_ready(function(){
var frameID = getFrameID("player");
if (frameID) { //If the frame exists
    player = new YT.Player(frameID, {
        playerVars: { 
       'rel': 0, 
       'enablejsapi': 1 
    }, 
        events: {
          'onReady': onPlayerReady
        }
    });
}
});
```

I've also tried removing the quotation marks from 'rel', no luck. This is the only player object in my code, so I can't think of this being "overridden" anywhere else in my code (though will post more code here if relevant).

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, in my case the error was because I was using an existing iFrame with a hardcoded URL, I just had to add &rel=0 to the end of that. Works for all videos selected after, too.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
player = new YT.Player(frameID, {
playerVars: { 
   playerVars: {rel: 0},
   enablejsapi: 1 
},
```